# How can I get the index of prev and next item in OwlCarousel2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slideshow, owl-carousel-2

How can I get the index of the next and prev items in OwlCarousel for setting background images for the next and prev buttons? I made the basic variant of carousel.

```
$('.cat-slides').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    center: true,
    loop: true,
    autoWidth:true,
});
```

I need to get index's of prev & next for set the img's as background for prev & next buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First it's necessary to understand this carousel library generates "clones" of your slides, placing half the clones before your slides, and the remaining clones after your slides. This is what an example with 12 items looks like:

[image: owl DOM clones]

So to get the correct index of the button in relation to the active item, you need to subtract half the number of clones from the active item's index. Here's how you'd go about it:

```
$(".cat-slides").on('changed.owl.carousel', function() {
    // get the index of the active item
    const activeItem = document.querySelector('.owl-carousel.cat-slides .active');
    const allItems = Array.from(activeItem.parentNode.children);
    const index = allItems.indexOf(activeItem);

    // count the clones
    const cloneCount = activeItem.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.cloned').length;

    // take the previous/next item's index, then subtract half the clones from it
    const prevButtonIndex = index - 1 - cloneCount / 2;
    const nextButtonIndex = index + 1 - cloneCount / 2;

    // get references to the next and previous button elements
    const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.owl-dot');
    const nextButton = allButtons[nextButtonIndex];
    const prevButton = allButtons[prevButtonIndex];

    // example of how you'd change the background image of each button
    if (nextButton) nextButton.style.backgroundImage = "path/to/next/image";
    if (prevButton) prevButton.style.backgroundImage = "path/to/prev/image";
});
```

The next bit you're missing is how to get the previous/next images, but I'm only answering the question you've asked. If anything is unclear, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to get the index,

```
var owl = $('.cat-slides');
owl.owlCarousel();
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function (e) {
      var currentindex = e.item.index;
      return currentindex;
});
```

Comment: I did it. And now I try to get prev&next index (i now about inc and dec) for setting bg image for prev&next buttons.